# When creating SyntheticBean using BeanCreator, I get NPE when bean is instantiated

Tags: quarkus

I'm creating a Quarkus extension and one of the things I need is to use the replacement for *AfterBeanDiscovery.addBean()*.

But I get a NullPointerException when Quarkus tries to instantiate the bean (in generated code, so no idea what is *null*)

This is the slimmed down code but still has the same problem. I created a *processor* with following BuildStep.

```
    @BuildStep
    SyntheticBeanBuildItem syntheticExample(BeanArchiveIndexBuildItem beanArchiveIndex) {

        return SyntheticBeanBuildItem.configure(ExampleBean.class).scope(Singleton.class)
                .creator(ExampleCreator.class)
                .done();

    }
```

And the *Creator* is just

```
    private static class ExampleCreator implements BeanCreator<ExampleBean> {

        @Override
        public ExampleBean create(CreationalContext<ExampleBean> creationalContext, Map<String, Object> map) {
            return new ExampleBean("X");
        }
    }
```

When I use the `ExampleBean` within a JAX-RS resource, I get following Stacktrace when I try to access an endpoint in that resource.

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error injecting be.rubus.microstream.quarkus.integration.ExampleBean be.rubus.microstream.quarkus.GreetingResource.exampleBean
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:368)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:218)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error injecting be.rubus.microstream.quarkus.integration.ExampleBean be.rubus.microstream.quarkus.GreetingResource.exampleBean
        at be.rubus.microstream.quarkus.GreetingResource_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
        at be.rubus.microstream.quarkus.GreetingResource_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:111)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at be.rubus.microstream.quarkus.integration.ExampleBean_f7ae08679933a92c66701907ce1ebba818ff26b3_Synthetic_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
        at be.rubus.microstream.quarkus.integration.ExampleBean_f7ae08679933a92c66701907ce1ebba818ff26b3_Synthetic_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
        ... 34 more
```

What am I missing?

Reproducer for the issue : https://github.com/rdebusscher/quarkus-syntheticbean

Comment: Do you have the code somewhere we can check?

Comment: @geoand Just an Quarkus Extension that is generated through maven plugin and the 2 main snippets in the post result in the error (ExampleBean is just a POJO with 1 String property set by constructor and a getter)

Comment: Best upload it to GitHub :)

Comment: Created a minimal reproducer for the issue. @geoand

Comment: You should probably use `supplier` instead of `creator` where the `Supplier` comes from a Quarkus Recorder

Comment: When using Supplier I get error that there is no default constructor (when using lambda as supplier) or ClassNotFound (on the BeanRecorder when using actual class that implements Supplier) or a wrong error about read-only of a property when using RuntieValue (_Cannot serialise field on object 'io.quarkus.runtime.RuntimeValue@38a1a797' as the property is read only_ but setter is present)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Quarkus ARC team provided the solution

The Scope was Singleton from Google Juice and not the CDI one.  Problem is not reported correctly due to insufficient checks within `io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanConfiguratorBase#scope(java.lang.Class<? extends java.lang.annotation.Annotation>)`